# Cannot send message to channel using discord.py

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

I have the code below, am trying to send messages to a discord channel every 60 sec. the login is successful but nothing happens on the channel.

```
async def my_background_task():
    await client.wait_until_ready()
    counter = 0
    channel = discord.Object(id='608412706310979613')
    while not client.is_closed:
        counter += 1
        await channel.send(counter)
    await client.send_message(channel, counter)
    await asyncio.sleep(60) # task runs every 60 seconds
```

I expect to receive an incremented count every 60 sec on the specified channel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If version of your `discord.py` is over `1.1.0`, you can use `discord.ext.tasks`.

Your job can be written with it like below.

```
from discord.ext import tasks, commands

bot = commands.Bot()
counter = 0

@tasks.loop(seconds=60)
async def my_background_task():
    global counter
    channel = bot.get_channel('608412706310979613')
    if channel is not None:
        counter += 1
        await channel.send(counter)

bot.run(token)
my_background_task.start()
```

Related documentation: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/tasks/index.html